# How make work tag video in mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I have this code for watch a video in the web page:

```
<video src="intro.mp4" preload="auto" autoplay loop></video>
```

Work fine in Pc but in mobile devices does not work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [most browsers/platforms support MP4](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mpeg4), you might need to add in multiple formats.  So, the issue could be that you are only offering MP4 as the format.

```
<video preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" controls="true">
    <source src="intro.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="intro.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="intro.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Also just an FYI that the autoplay might not work on a mobile device.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try this option

Comment: FYI: Autoplay is disabled in iOS by default, so that it doesn't eat up a user's metered bandwidth with auto-playing videos.